# RxJava - Multiple tasks in a observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a list that contain many objects and i will use it as observable, Each object has two url, In each consuming, I should ensure both url downloaded successfully, If one of url did not downloaded, RxJava should be stop the job, I am new in RxJava and i can just do simple works.

This is my object

```
public class mediaChunk
{
    public String audioChunkUrl;
    public String videoChunkUrl;
}

List<mediaChunk> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

one approach would be:

1. use the `Observable.fromIterable` factory method to setup the stream from the initial `List<MediaChunk>`
2. `flatMap` each emission from that stream and use the `Observable.just` factory method to create a stream of audio + video URLs from each `MediaChunk` instance

the result is a flattened stream of URLs for which subscribers can plug in their own `onNext`, `onError`, and `onComplete` handlers.

the code would look something like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(
        Arrays.asList(
            new MediaChunk("audio-1", "video-1"),
            new MediaChunk("audio-2", "video-2"),
            new MediaChunk("audio-3", "video-3")
        ))
        .flatMap(chunk -> Observable.just(chunk.audioChunkUrl, chunk.videoChunkUrl))
        .subscribe(
            value -> {
              System.out.println("## onNext(" + value + ")");
            },
            error -> {
              System.out.println("## onError(" + error.getMessage() + ")");
            },
            () -> {
              System.out.println("## onComplete()");
            }
        );
```

not sure if this fits the bill, but hopefully it's enough to at least inspire some thought.

*Update - example mapping emissions to `Completable`*

```
Observable.fromIterable(
    Arrays.asList(
        new MediaChunk("audio-1", "video-1"),
        new MediaChunk("audio-2", "video-2"),
        new MediaChunk("audio-3", "video-3")
    ))
    .flatMap(chunk -> Observable.just(chunk.audioChunkUrl, chunk.videoChunkUrl))
    .flatMapCompletable(url -> {
      return Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
        return "## ...handling network call for [" + url + "]";
      });
    })
    .subscribe(
        () -> {
          System.out.println("## onComplete()");
        },
        error -> {
          System.out.println("## onError(" + error.getMessage() + ")");
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks homerman.Should i implement downloading job in subscribe, or i should implement it in flatMap?  
like this:    `.flatMap(chunk -> Observable.just(chunk.videoUrl, chunk.audioUrl).doOnNext(value -> {
                    download(value);
                }))`

Comment: there may be a compelling technical argument for one approach over the other, but i can't think of it. try it both ways and see which is the better fit for your design. i might offer some food for thought - if the download job is simply stashing the files somewhere and the subscriber doesn't really have any work to do in `onNext`, then you might consider converting each emission to a `Completable` to simply signal that all the downloads have completed, or something failed. i've updated my answer with an example.